# I am trying to make a helper class for admobs in my app

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a Admobs ADHelper class in my app. The Code for this class is:

```
  import UIKit
   import Firebase
   import GoogleMobileAds

    class AdHelper {
    static let shared = AdHelper()

    func initAdMobBannerView(inViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> GADBannerView {
        var adMobBannerView = GADBannerView()
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            // iPhone
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewController.view.frame.size.height, width: 320, height: 50)
        } else  {
            // iPad
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 468, height: 60))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewController.view.frame.size.height, width: 468, height: 60)
        }
        adMobBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-2722404425168911/4464296386"
        adMobBannerView.rootViewController = viewController

        adMobBannerView.delegate = viewController as? GADBannerViewDelegate
        //viewController.addSubview(adMobBannerView)

        let request = GADRequest()
        adMobBannerView.load(request)
        return adMobBannerView
        UIView.beginAnimations("showBanner", context: nil)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        adMobBannerView.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

and I am trying to call this class from my another view controller:

func playAd() {

```
 let adMobBannerView = AdHelper.shared.initAdMobBannerView(inViewController: self)
view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)
```

}

I call this function in viewdidload as playAd()

No ads are still loading up!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definition of your class:

```
class AdHelper: UIViewController
```

Why does it have to extend `UIViewController`? It is a helper class, so it shouldn't have to extend `UIViewController`.

You say:

> The problem is ads are not showing up at all when I do this but all of this code is put in the same view controller (without using shared class), they show up.

Take a look at your `initAdMobBanner` method, this line for instance:

```
adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 320, height: 50)
```

You're setting the `frame` of your `adMobBannerView` to start at the height of `view.frame`...but the questions are....how large is `view`? Where is it initialised?

And later on:

```
view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)
```

Here you are adding your `adMobBannerView` to `view`, but what is the size of `view`?

This also explains:

> but all of this code is put in the same view controller (without using shared class), they show up

Yes...because here you know what size the view is, and you can add content to it.

What I'm hinting at here is, that I think you should create a separate class that does *not* inherit from `UIViewController` and then have a method that takes a `UIViewController` as parameter and uses that to create a new `adMobBannerView`.

Something like:

```
class AdHelper {
   static let shared = AdHelper()

    func initAdMobBannerView(inViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> GADBannerView {
        var adMobBannerView = GADBannerView() 
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            // iPhone
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewController.view.frame.size.height, width: 320, height: 50)
        } else  {
            // iPad
            adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 468, height: 60))
            adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewController.view.frame.size.height, width: 468, height: 60)
        }
        adMobBannerView.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID
        adMobBannerView.rootViewController = viewController

        return adMobBannerView
    }
}
```

Which your could then use in your normal ViewControllers like so:

```
func playAd() {
    let adMobBannerView = AdHelper.shared.initAdMobBannerView(inViewController: self)
    view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)
    let request = GADRequest()
    adMobBannerView.load(request)
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for replying promptly. I tried your code but getting this when I try to use in my normal ViewController  Type 'AdHelper' has no member shared

Comment: I replaced let adMobBannerView = AdHelper.shared.initAdMobBannerView(inViewController: self)
view.addSubview(adMobBannerView) with let adMobBannerView = AdHelper.sharedHelper.initAdMobBannerView(inViewController: self)
view.addSubview(adMobBannerView) and the error is gone but still no ads are coming up. I have also removed UIViewController from definition of helper class. Could you please help!

Comment: Ah! Sorry. I updated my answer and renamed `sharedHelper` to `shared`

Comment: Thanks, however the problem is when i am just using shared, I get an error saying Type 'AdHelper' has no member shared.

Comment: I tried the updated code and there are no errors now but ads are still not showing up. Could you please look into this asap and help?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look why the banner still won't show up in view controllers?

Comment: @KunalKapoor its morning here in Europe so no, I haven't looked into this :). But OK, you're saying that no ads are showing up. Try setting a breakpoint in your `ViewController` in the `view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)` line. Then inspect the `adMobBannerView` you've just created. What is its frame? its size? its position? Does those values make sense? Also, I didn't add the lines that load the `GADRequest`, so try adding those and see if that helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that you were in Europe. I did put breakpoint and it seems all good. However, what lines do I put to load the GADRequest. I have updated the question to show what I am doing. Please help!

Comment: @KunalKapoor You could try adding them to your `playAd()` function. I've updated my answer. Where do you call your `playAd()` method? Is that in `viewDidLoad()` `viewWillAppear` or something else?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just updated my code as suggested and tried to load GADRequest from playAd() but still no ad banner showed up in the view controller. My playAd() is called from viewdidload(). What should i do?

Comment: OK, could you verify the size and position of the frame of `adMobBannerView` and show it here...just to be sure that it has a valid value. Also...is the `adMobBannerView` visible? (try setting its `backgroundColor` to something and see if it shows up). And finally...if you implement some of the delegate methods of  `GADBannerViewDelegate`..are they called then? (just to know how far we get)